# How does the pool work in Glory to Rome?

Tags: glory-to-rome

I am reading my Glory to Rome instruction booklet and I do not understand how the pool works.

Are players free to choose any card they wish from the pool, or are they just supposed to draw the top card?

Answer (score 4):

The Spanish version of the game has really badly translated instructions. The English version (latest version downloadable [here](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/78587/blackbox-edition-rulebook-pdf)) is clearer (emphasis added):

> Place all the **face up** Order cards [which are revealed during setup] in the middle of the playing surface 
>   beside the pile of Jacks — they are the starting Pool.

Page 4 shows an image of the cards in the Pool face-up.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question directly, *yes*, you may choose any card you like from the pool, especially since they're face-up.